# Issue of downloading jquery file with ResolveClientUrl asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i think there is some bug in my ResolveClientUrl syntax. what would be the right syntax. please help. thanks

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  window.jQuery || document.write("<script src="+<%=  this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js") %>"+>\x3C/script>")</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a typo in your code. check out your concatenations and also, you need to escape some html characters like "/", ">", etc etc

the ff code should correct it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery ||
        document.write("<script type='text\/javascript' src='<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js") %>'><\/script>"); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ResolveClientUrl` returns relative to current page. You may try `ResolveUrl` which will return relative to **site root**!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">  window.jQuery || document.write("<script src="+<%=
      Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js") %>"+>\x3C/script>")</script>
```